# Passing URL with QueryString to UIWebView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am having a problem similar to this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6319/problem-with-webview-and-url

Using a `UIWebView`, I am trying to pass a URL with a querystring. The URI looks like this: `"Content/Content/holder.html/?contentpath=/test.html"`

Without the querystring, the document displays correctly. However, with the querystring, I get the following error:
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server."`

It seems as though it's not separating the query string.
I've read some C solutions, but I can't manage to reflect that in my C# solution; particularly

```
NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];   
NSString *queryString = @"?param1=1"; 
NSString *URLwithQueryString = [URLString stringByAppendingString: queryString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10444/uiwebview-loadrequest-encoding-url-so-becomes-3f

The UIWebView does not like spaces in the URL:

```
var escapedBundlePath = Uri.EscapeUriString(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath);
var myUrl = "Path/To/File/Test.html?var1=hello&var2=world";
var nsUrl = new NSUrl(Path.Combine(escapedBundlePath, myUrl));

WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(nsUrl));
```